# Prove: Full Rank and a solution os linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm studying for my exam of linear algebra.. I want to prove the following corollary:

> Given $A \in{R^{n\times n}}$, there is a solution $x$ to $Ax = y$ for all $y$, if and only if $A$
>   has rank $m$ (full row rank).

I know that the rank of a matrix is the maximum number of columns (rows respectively) that are linearly independent and is defined by:

> $\operatorname{Img} (A) = \operatorname{Rg} (A):= y \in{C^m}:y = Ax, x \in{C^n}$

My problem is that I can not find a way to relate the two concepts in order to reach a formal proof. Any help?

Comment: sorry for the notation used but do not know how to express formulas in LaTeX notation in this page

Comment: use `$` to embed the inline math. Use `$$` to embed the display math.

Comment: And use `>` to quote material. See my edit.

Comment: If you linear map is injective then it is onto, since you are considering maps from n-dimensional to n-dimensional spaces. If it is injective then linearly independent set is mapped to a linearly independent set also.

Comment: There is a possible typo here. The matrix is $n\times n$ but the question states the full row rank $ = m$?? Is $m$ a typo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linear equations given by $Ax = b$ have a solution if and only if $\operatorname{rank}(A|b) = \operatorname{rank}(A)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090742/linear-equations-given-by-ax-b-have-a-solution-if-and-only-if-operatorname)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the system $Ax = y$ as
$$ \pmatrix{\mid & \mid &  & \mid \\
 a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_n \\
\mid & \mid &  & \mid } 
\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n} = \mathbf{y} \tag{1} $$
or
$$ x_1 \pmatrix{\mid \\ a_1 \\ \mid } + x_2 \pmatrix{\mid \\ a_2 \\ \mid } + \cdots + x_n \pmatrix{\mid \\ a_n \\ \mid } = \mathbf{y} \tag{2} $$
For every $\mathbf{y} \in \Bbb{R}^n$, equation $(2)$ has a unique solution $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ **iff**  the vectors $\{ a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n \}$ form a basis of $\Bbb{R}^n$, which is true since $A$ is $n\times n$ and full rank.

Comment: **Remark 1:** The proof depends on the [definition of basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Definition). If $\{ a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n \}$ is a basis of $\Bbb{R}^n$ then for **every** vector $y \in \Bbb{R}^n$ there are unique "coordinates" for $y$ in terms of $\{ a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n \}$. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: **Remark 2:** However, you will need to re-write this proof as $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftarrow$ parts, which is easy to do, once you know that full rank $\Leftrightarrow$ linear independence $\Leftrightarrow$ basis $\Leftrightarrow$ unique coordinates.