# number of solutions and rank

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a matrix A of $a\times b$. If we know the how the rank of the matrix is related to a and b, we can determine (maybe not exactly) the number of solutions for the system.

Now, if we know the number of solutions for the system (infinite, for example), what's the relationship between rank(A) and a and b? How do you prove that? Thanks for answering, I'm so confused.

Comment: Can you think of a system that has a number of solutions besides 0, 1, or infinity? If $x_0$ and $x_1$ are solutions to a system, what about any other point that lies on the line which connects them?

Comment: My bad, by the number of solutions I do mean either 0, 1 or infinity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove: Full Rank and a solution os linear system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187181/prove-full-rank-and-a-solution-os-linear-system)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The null space of an $a \times b$ matrix $A$ has dimension $b - \text{rank}(A)$.
The column space has dimension $\text{rank}(A)$.

If a system $Ax = y$ has infinitely many solutions, the null space must have dimension at least $1$.

If a system $Ax = y$ has  one solution, the null space must have dimension $0$
and the column space must have dimension $a$.

If a system $Ax = y$ has no solution, the column space must have dimension less than $a$.

Comment: If a system $Ax=y$ has infinitely many solutions, the null space must have dimension at least 1. Why is this true?

Comment: Because if the null space had dimension $0$, any solution would be unique.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still not quite sure how that is!!!

Comment: If $\text{nullity}(A) = 0$, does that mean the trivial solution is the only solution (unique)?

Comment: The difference between two solutions of $Ax=y$ is in the null space, so if the null space consists only of $0$ any solution is unique.